# Codeigniter generating html table (Trying to get property of none object)

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, controller, html-table

I am trying to generate a table to display my websites enquiries and add a column containing links(actions) for each of the enquiries.

Upon creating my table I am receiving the following error:

```
Message: Trying to get property of non-object (line 55)
```

My **controller** is as follows:

```
$this->table->set_heading('ID', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Email', 'Phone','Message','Date','Actions');

    $enquiries = $this->contact_model->get_table_enquiries($per_page,$offset);

    foreach($enquiries as $row) { 

        $links  = anchor('admin/enquiries/edit/' ,'Edit');
        $links .= anchor('admin/enquiries/delete/', 'Delete');

        $this->table->add_row(
            $row->id, //line 55
            $row->first_name,
            $row->last_name,
            $row->email_address,
            $row->phone_number,
            $row->message,
            $links   
        );
    }
        $viewdata['enquiries_table'] = $this->table->generate();
```

And the function in the **model** that gets the results:

```
  function get_table_enquiries($per_page,$offset)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
        $query=$this->db->get('contact',$per_page,$offset);

        return $query;
    }
```

How can I get my foreach loop to work and create the necessary rows and append the links???

Why am I receiving the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to try

```
 foreach ($enquiries->result() as $row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_table_enquiries($per_page,$offset)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
        $query=$this->db->get('contact',$per_page,$offset);

        return $query->result(); //do this
    }
```